# Ember.js / access to parent array within each - nested each

Tags: ember.js, each, nested-loops

I have the following Model in Ember.js:

```
 App.Fraction.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id          : 200,
        title       : "General",
        list        : 100,
        provider    : [400],

        attributes  : [800,801]
    }, {
        id          : 201,
        title       : "Kinder Preise",
        list        : 100,
        provider    : [400]
    }
 ];
```

Each Fraction has Providers and Attributes and each Provider has Services. I want to create a Table for each Provider with the `provider.services` as rows and the `attributes`as coloumns.

In my Template I tried this:

```
 {{#each provider}}
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <hr />

    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             {{#each ../attributes}}
                <th> {{title}} nothing happend!!!</th>
             {{/each}}
          </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
           {{#each services}}
              <tr>
                 <td> {{title }}</td>
                 {{#each attributes}}
                    <td>{{value}}</td>
                 {{/each}}
              </tr>
           {{/each}}
         </tbody>
       </table>
   {{/each}}
```

It seems like the path identifier "thing" does not work here. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Ember this is how you would do it:

```
 {{#each providers as |provider|}}
    <h3>{{provider.title}}</h3>
    <hr />

    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             {{#each attributes as |attr|}}
                <th> {{provider.title}} should work</th>
             {{/each}}
          </tr>
         </thead>
    </table>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Yep, there's a nice blog excerpt here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params